# border-image slicing differences between browsers

Tags: css

I'm seeing some significant differences in how browsers are repeating sliced border images.  It's easily demonstrated on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice

MacOS 10.14.6 Safari 12.1.2
[image: MacOS Safari]
MacOS 10.14.6 Firefox 91.0.1
[image: MacOS Firefox]
MacOS 10.14.6 Chrome 92.0.4515.159
[image: MacOS Chrome]

So it appears that Safari on MacOS Mojave has an issue.  Simple enough if that were the case.  But mobile browsers on iOS are also behaving differently.

iOS 14.6 Safari
[image: iOS Safari]
iOS 14.6 Firefox
[image: iOS Firefox]
iOS 14.6 Chrome
[image: iOS Chrome]

Does anyone have any insight into why these browsers behave differently?  Does anyone have insight into how to get the un-stretched results in all browsers that MacOS Firefox and Chrome have?

Comment: For mobile, iOS enforces all browsers to use the same rendering, which is why it performs uniformly bad on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you are seeing here is Safari behavior vs. the behavior of all other browsers, which sadly is a common frustration of many developers— Safari functioning differently and usually unexpectedly.

What you are seeing on iOS (mobile) is to be expected, because although there are different browser apps, all of them, even Chrome and Firefox are actually Safari (using the Safari browser engine, WebKit), simply reskinned with a different UI. There is only one iOS browser in actuality.

---

**Supporting source #1:** https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9lpmkh/

> As we all know Apple forces all third party browsers on iOS to use WebKit, essentially making them just re skinned versions of Safari; This puts Gecko Based Firefox and other Third party Browsers at a performance disadvantage.

---

**Supporting source #2:** https://www.quora.com/Is-Chrome-for-iOS-just-Safari-re-skinned

> Google wasn't just being lazy using Safari's rendering engine. Apple requires people making browsers to use the UIWebView object. [This] means “exactly the same rendering engine”.

---

To be clear, **this is a bug** in WebKit/Safari. I have opened an official bug report to resolve this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229803

Comment: Now that I understand the issue better, I have a workaround.  The SVG can be rescaled to the size the browser wants, e.g. <svg .. width="90" height="90">.  Then the slice and border width can be set such that the tiles do not distort, e.g. border-image: url(my.svg) 30 / 30px round.  Of course that doesn't change the fact that the CSS spec allows for the border-width to change and that Safari is not implementing it correctly.  But at least I can get this one page with this one SVG to not distort.

Comment: @lschult2 glad you managed to find a reliable workaround!

Answer (score 1):

This github link I encountered last time shows that border-image in safari is seems to be not solved.
https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/2366